# AppleScript - Reading a file that has been modified after script has compiled

Tags: io, applescript

I have an `iCal (Calendar)` alarm that is set to go off everyday. It parses a `csv` that contains emails and a date, then sends an email if it's the appropriate day. The `csv` is statically coded because I want it to run in the background.

Here is the code for reading the file:

```
set theLines to paragraphs of (read (open for access file "csv path"))
```

The problem I'm encountering is that if I modify the `csv` file (add or remove lines), it seems to read it incorrectly. From what I can tell, prior to modifying it, it works fine.
After I modify it (which I must do periodically), it doesn't read it correctly because it's basing it off of a cached version or something. My only thought is that I'm reading the file incorrectly. Is there a more appropriate way to read a file? I'm new to AppleScript, but not to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to "open for access". Try this:

```
set theLines to paragraphs of (read "/Users/Grant/path/to/your/file.txt")
```

or

```
set theLines to paragraphs of (do shell script "cat '/Users/Grant/path/to/your/file.txt'")
```

Comment: `read` treats files as MacRoman unless you add `as «class utf8»`.

Comment: That would have caused a problem in his first script as well.

Comment: I haven't tested it extensively as an alarm, but testing it in AppleScript Editor worked great. Thanks!